# How to use restricted Code through SWIG

Tags: python, swig

I have a  code as mentioned following ..

File : a.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef ALLOW
int check(int n);
#endif
```

SWIG:  test.i

```
%module test
%{
  #include "a.h"
%}

%include "a.h"
```

CMD:  `swig -python test.i`

this is generating a _test.so , when i am importing this library to python this is not displaying  ***check function*** defined.

In Make I could have used `-D` option, say  `gcc -DALLOW` a.c.

How can I achieve the same using SWIG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As easy as it looks - `swig -DALLOW -python test.i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define preprocessor macros within the SWIG interface itself (i.e. inside the .i file).

So in your case you might want to do:

```
%module test
%{
  #include "a.h"
%}

#define ALLOW
%include "a.h"
```

That's enough to make SWIG itself "see inside" the `#ifdef`, but if you want to have `ALLOW` defined within the generated warpper code as well you'd want to add:

```
%module test
%{
  #define ALLOW
  #include "a.h"
%}

#define ALLOW    
%include "a.h"
```

because the contents of the `%{ ... %}` are passed straight through to that generated code whereas the plain `#define` only influences how SWIG itself sees the file.